# использование php кода в многострочных переменных, заданных через <<<

Tags: php, строки, переменные

Подскажите, есть ли возможность использовать код в многострочных переменных PHP, заданных следующим образом

```
$str = <<<BIG_STRING

BIG_STRING;
```

Например, что-то вроде такого:

```
<php

    $str = <<<BIG_STRING
 <b><?php echo (i == 2) ? "test #1" : "test #2"; ?></b>
    BIG_STRING;

    echo $str;

</php>
```

Comment: Разве вам что-то мешает __[сохранить в переменную](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a423d60ebcc555ee76a978016f24920796c65dd)__ результат выражения из условия, и передать эту переменную в heredoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитав немного, решил свою проблему следующим образом:

```
    function check($src, $dst)
    {       
        return ($src == $dst) ? "test #1" : "test #2";
    }

    $_ = function ( $v ) {
    return $v;

    $str = <<<BIG_STRING
 <b>{$_( check($i, 2) )}></b>
    BIG_STRING;

    echo $str;
```

Все заработало

Вот только не понял, зачем нужна промежуточная функция $_

Answer (score 0):

[Статья](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) по теме

Согласно документации, такой текст ведет себя аналогично тексту в двойных кавычках. Следовательно, самый простой вариант - создать новую переменную и использовать ее без выражений.

Comment: И старнно у вас php-код обознчается `<php ... </php>`